# How to use the Dateparse function to create a date range from year to year i.e 2020-2021

Tags: tableau-desktop

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a calculated field of the 'Seasons' column using the date parse function in order to create a date range rather than using the column as a string as it limits some of the visualizations I am able to create.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tableau has not a built-in function to generate a calendar, like `Calendar()` DAX function of PowerBI.

Probably the fastest and best way to achieve the same result is to generate a list of values in Microsoft Excel o Google Spreadsheet, save it as CSV and import it in your Tableau workbook.
Once you have imported you can join the original data source with this new calendar. As you can't leave the `JOIN` conditions empty you can make the join on a calculated field based on your `Season` column or just using fake columns, as described in [this post](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6WaT/all-dates-between-2-given-dates-or-start-and-end-date).